# How do I create a Parameter class(es) to be passed to custom report classes?

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, report

I am working with a custom report engine that uses XML and XSL to output the report data to the browser. Each report can have multiple parameters of different value types (integers, strings, dates).

Each report has its own class (inheriting from a base report class) and XSLT that gets the data from the DB based on the parameters, generates the xml, and styles it with the XSLT. However currently, the parameters are listed individually in each class. I think it is more efficient to create a Parameter class, have a generic list of all the parameters, add the parameters to the list when the report data is requested, then the base class can loop through the list of parameters and output the appropriate XML.

Here is what the code looks like now:

```
public class Report
{
    //Common functions used by all reports
}

public class OrderDetailReport : Report
{
    public long? Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public long? Parameter2 { get; set; }

    public XElement CreateXML()
    {
        var xml = new XElement();

        xml.Add(GetXMLParameters());

        //Get Data and generate XML

        return xml;
    }

    public XElement GetXMLParameters()
    {
        var parameters = new XElement("Parameters",
                            new XElement("Parameter",
                                    new XAttribute("Name", "Parameter1"),
                                    new XAttribute("Value", Parameter1)),
                            new XElement("Parameter",
                                    new XAttribute("Name", "Parameter2"),
                                    new Attribute("Value", Parameter2)));
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

What should the `Parameter` class look like so that it can handle all different value types and be able to format the value that is displayed on the screen?

**EDIT:**

I want to be able to move the `GetXMLParameters()` function to the base class and have a list something like `List<Parameter>` in the base that `GetXMLParameters()` will loop through and create the XML.

This will avoid having `GetXMLParameters()` in each `CustomReport` class.

Thanks. I hope this was clear.
Oran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at serialization. There are many xml serializers in .net (wcf, xml etc) that will convert your objects for you. You can also shape the xml output by using attributes on the members you wish to serialise.

I offer up this solution because as long as your class can be serialized it will always work and allow for future growth.

**AS REQUESTED:**

```
public static class SerialiserHelper
{
        public static string Serialize(this object @object)
        {
            try
            {

               DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(@object.GetType());


                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {

                    serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, @object);

                    var encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);

                    return encoder.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(memoryStream.Length));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }



        public static T DeSerialize<T>(this string serializedObject)
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

            var encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encoder.GetBytes(serializedObject)))
            {   
                return (T)serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this will solve my problem. I clarified what I am trying to do in the question.

Comment: Avoid inheritance. Go for composition instead. The code will be less brittle. When dealing with object transformations which by the look of your code it is, use the visitor pattern.

Comment: look at the problem as if your passing in data into a function and getting a result out. If you think that way, you start seeing the bigger picture of what actually is happening. an Object goes in, XML comes out. If you use the serialization stuff, then all the problems with class hierarchy and inheritance go away to some extent, because your using the generic code that the kind people at Microsoft have designed for you.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. Can you give me a code example of how it would look?

Comment: Hope the code helps, its just an Extension method, that is for all objects, BEWARE THERE BE MONSTERS HERE. If your object can not be serialized, or has not been designed to be serialized, then this extention will throw exceptions. Take a look at the DataContractSerializer for more info. This is just one of the XML serializers. I use it because it gives me more control over the output XML. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look about reflection :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.reflection.aspx

Comment: Can you explain how that would help?

Comment: It allow you to browse easily object attributes